# Getting started with an existing github project for nitrous

Tags: nitrousio

I followed the directions on "Connecting to Github" article, and my github account has the nitrous keys.

I'm not able to find a way to connect an Nitrous box to an existing github repo. I have a rails project on github that I'd like to use with Nitrous.

I then tried downloading the Nitrous Desktop for Mac. I enabled File Sync. From the command line, I navigated to ~/Nitrous/BOX and I did a git clone from the github repo. The Nitrous web IDE does not show any of the synced files.

Update: The "workspace" folder does not automatically open up. Be sure to click on the triangle =)

I'm guessing this a feature that is just rolling out and maybe I'm trying to use Github integration too soon?

Ps. The documentation here http://help.nitrous.io/faq-adding-project/ on cloning from Git needs updating.

Answer (score 1):

I use the command line tools **git** to perform a git repository synchronization in Nitrous.IO.
I use BitBucket but it's exactly the same thing with GitHub.

In GitHub I found this documentation : [GitHub fork repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)

All these actions need to be performed into the **Consol** windows from Nitrous.IO.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late to answer this question but you need to Add the SSH key to your Github account.

Nitrous leave quite good instructions here

http://help.nitrous.io/github-add-key/